# Can't seem to find error or set SQL variables in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
        DELIMITER $
        ​
        CREATE PROCEDURE create_cit_table()
        BEGIN

        ​SET @totalid = (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM entity.name_search);
        SET @i = 1;

        WHILE @i <= @totalid DO

        SET @name = (SELECT name_friendly FROM entity.name_search WHERE id = @i);

        INSERT INTO tls_name_frnd_citations
        (SELECT p1.name_friendly, a.publn_ops,  COUNT(distinct a2.appln_id) as cit_count FROM tls201_appln a  
        INNER JOIN tls211_pat_publn b1 ON b1.appln_id = a.appln_id 
        INNER JOIN tls212_citation c ON c.cited_pat_publn_id = b1.pat_publn_id 
        INNER JOIN tls211_pat_publn b2 ON b2.pat_publn_id = c.pat_publn_id 
        INNER JOIN tls201_appln a2 ON a2.appln_id = b2.appln_id  
        INNER JOIN tls207_pers_appln pa1 ON pa1.appln_id = a.appln_id 
        INNER JOIN entity.combined p1 ON p1.person_id = pa1.person_id  
        INNER JOIN tls207_pers_appln pa2 ON pa2.appln_id = b2.appln_id 
        INNER JOIN entity.combined p2 ON p2.person_id = pa2.person_id  
        WHERE p1.name_friendly LIKE CONCAT(@name) 
        AND p2.name_friendly NOT LIKE CONCAT(@name) 
        GROUP BY a.publn_ops, p1.name_friendly 
        ORDER BY cit_count DESC
        LIMIT 20;);

        SET @i = @i + 1;

        END WHILE;

        END$

        DELIMITER ;
```

The above SQL PROCEDURE is giving me error at the `SET @totalid = (SELECT COUNT(' at line 1`
 Syntax Error I can't seem to find the error is there any other way to assign variable in MYSQL

Comment: `SET @totalid = (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM entity.name_search);` did you try running the same query from Query Editor as a saparate query?

Comment: Yes sometime works sometime not;

Comment: What sometime work and sometime not?

Comment: Hmm the error is mainly on the set @totalid line. The syntax looks correct but when I cut and paste the procedure from the question this line  seems to have some non printing characters in (id) part - if I delete the line (and remove the extra ; from the select..limit 20 the procedure compiles. If I retype the line the procedure compiles.